# ACTION_SEND with cwac-provider?

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

How I can start ACTION_SEND intent with cwac-provider?

I tried code below (modified code from provider demo)

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    i.setType("application/pdf");
    //i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, PROVIDER.buildUpon().appendPath("help.pdf").build());

    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    startActivity(i);
    //finish();

  }
```

When I choosed an mail app for sending pdf, the mail app crashed.

*java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo {com.commonsware.cwac.provider.demo /com.commonsware.cwac.provider.demo.MainActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND (has extras) }*

Next code works fine:

```
Intent theIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
theIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
theIntent.setType("application/pdf");
File f = new File("/mnt/sdcard/task.pdf");  
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(f);
theIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
```

Comment: `commonsware-cwac` is a Stack Overflow tag. You cannot "start `ACTION_SEND` intent" with a Stack Overflow tag.

Comment: When you read [the documentation for `ACTION_SEND`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND), and when you read [the training material on `ACTION_SEND`](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html), what did you learn?

Comment: I wrote more information devoted to my question. I hope it's clear now.

Comment: I have no explanation why your device or emulator would be giving you different results for equivalent `Intent` objects. The value of the `EXTRA_STREAM` extra does not control `Intent` routing.

Comment: It is bad. I test on another device and got: error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)